# Integral of recursive base function Splines/Nurbs

Tags: definite-integrals, spline

I'm solving a problem using NURBS and at this moment I have to integrate the basic functions which are recursively defined like

$$
N_{i0}(u) = 
\begin{cases}
1  \ \ \ \ \mathrm{if} \ u_{i} \le u < u_{i+1} \\
0  \ \ \ \ \mathrm{else}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
N_{ij} = \dfrac{u-u_{i}}{u_{i+j} - u_{i}} \cdot N_{i, j-1} + \dfrac{u_{i+j+1} - u}{u_{i+j+1} - u_{i+1}} \cdot N_{i+1, j-1}
$$

That implies that $N_{kj}$ is a $j$-polynomial, that is, we can write $N_{kj}$ like $(a_0 + a_1 u + \cdots + a_{j} u^{j})$ in the interval $\left[u_{i}, \ u_{i+1}\right]$

And I would like to calculate the definite integrate $N_{kj}$ in the interval $\left[u_{i}, \ u_{i+1}\right]$ using the definite integrals of $N_{k,j-1}$ and $N_{k+1,j-1}$. So, I tried:

$$
I = \int_{u_{i}}^{u_{i+1}} N_{kj} \ du = \underbrace{\int_{u_i}^{u_{i+1}} \dfrac{u-u_{k}}{u_{k+j} - u_{k}} \cdot N_{k, j-1} \ du}_{I_1}  +  \underbrace{\int_{u_{i}}^{u_{i+1}}\dfrac{u_{k+j+1} - u}{u_{k+j+1} - u_{k+1}} \cdot N_{k+1, j-1} \ du}_{I_2}
$$

using partial decomposition

$$
I_{1} = \left[\dfrac{u-u_{k}}{u_{k+j}-u_{k}} \cdot \int N_{k,j-1} \ du \right]_{u_{i}}^{u_{i+1}} - \dfrac{1}{u_{k+j}-u_{k}}\int_{u_{i}}^{u_{i+1}} \left( \int N_{k+1, j-1} \ du\right) \ du
$$

and the same happens for $I_2$. The problem is that I don't have the indefinite integral of $N_{k,j-1}$ (because it's hard to get it), and I can't go any further.

My final objective is to calculate the matrix $M_{ij}$ using $M_{i-1, j-1}$, $M_{i,j-1}$ and $M_{i+1, j-1}$

$$
M_{ij} = \int_{u_{i}}^{u_{i+1}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
N_{i-j}^2 & N_{i-j}N_{i-j+1} & \cdots & N_{i-j}N_{i} \\
N_{i-j+1}N_{i-j} & N_{i-j+1}^2 & \cdots & N_{i-j+1}N_{i} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
N_{i}N_{i-j} & N_{i}N_{i-j+1} & \cdots & N_{i}^2
\end{bmatrix}_{(j+1) \times (j+1)}
\ du
$$

Until now, I got $M_{i0}$, $M_{i1}$, $M_{i2}$, but I'm having problems to find the $M_{i3}$ and so on.  $h_i = u_{i+1} - u_{i}$

$$
M_{i0} = h_{i} \cdot \left[1\right]
$$
$$
M_{i1} = \dfrac{h_{i}}{6}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$M_{i2}$ is more complex, but I got a closed formula for it depending on $h_{i-1}$ and $h_{i+1}$.

Comment: NURBS usually stands for 'non-uniform _rational_ B-Spline'; that is to say, the coordinates are usually homogeneous / projective rather than affine. (e.g. in three-space, x/y/z/w rather than just x/y/z) This plays havoc with some of the computations. Is this a consideration for you at all?

Comment: Until this moment I'm working only with B-Spline, but I would like to do the same (if possible) with the rational after getting the equations for B-Splines

Comment: Rational curves cause numerous difficulties, especially if you're trying to do integration, so you're better off sticking with polynomial curves. Even the original promoters of NURBS now admit that they were a bad idea.